# Can't get Location using GPS_PROVIDER

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm developing a app in which I need location of user using GPS. I am getting null value in the object of location instead of coordinates. But while using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` I am getting result. I want the same result using GPS.

Here is my code:

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable;
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        System.out.println("enable");
        System.out.println(status);
    }
   // mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    try {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       // LocationProvider BestProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            System.out.println("test5");
            location =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,1, this);
            System.out.println(locationManager);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                System.out.println(location);
                //requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    System.out.println("latitude:"+latitude);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fail");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Location object called `location` is always null because it's never assigned a value anywhere before this check is done

```
if (location != null)
```

Did you mean to assign it a value like this?

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Please also read the note in the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) javadoc about which permissions it is necessary to hold to get results from a GPS provider.  You will need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

Lastly, please note that it can take some time for a GPS to obtain a lock for accurate data.  When you use getLastKnownLocation, it is not guaranteed to have data immediately available.  You may have to wait for the first location update.  In that case, you should be using a listener to wait for the first accurate location.

Please also see the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) for the best information on using location providers.

Comment: I've assign the value like location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Comment: That's because getLastKnownLocation can still return null (according to the javadoc).

Comment: But it is working in case of NETWORK_PROVIDER @Doug Stevenson

Comment: if getLastKnownLocation can return null then what should I usse

Comment: I changed my answer to include more details.  There is lots of documentation to follow to use location providers correctly.